# How to fetch a new URL and update response object outside scrapy shell?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Using `scrapy shell` I can use the `fetch` method to grasp the content of a new URL. This method automatically update `response` object, as the following code demonstrate (see the comment):

```py
items = response.css('article')
for i in items:
    title = i.css('a[class="item-link "]::text').get()
    price = i.css('span[class="item-price h2-simulated"]::text').get()
    rooms = i.css('span[class="item-detail"]::text').get() 
    meters = i.css('span[class="item-detail"]:nth-of-type(2)::text').get()
    url = response.urljoin(i.css('a[class="item-link "]').attrib['href'])
    fetch(url, redirect=False)
    # After fetch() is called the response object is updated 
    # and I can fetch new informations
    loc = response.xpath('/html/body/script[9]').get()
    latitude = re.findall('latitude:"([-.0-9]+)"', loc)[0]
    longitude = re.findall('longitude:"([-.0-9]+)"', loc)[0]
```

But I don't know how to do the same outside `scrapy shell`, using `Spider` class and its methods.

Comment: Have you completed the [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) yet?

Comment: Yep, but the only solution I could conceive was to build a new parse method to be called into a `Request` callback. It worked, but not as good as in `fetch`. For two reasons: it put the new links into a queue so I can't grab the information in a proper order, besides this solution makes, I think, increase the number of connections required, so I receive a 403 response after a few iterations, this never happened with `fetch`

Comment: The order bit is the way Scrapy is meant to work. Concurrency (simultaneous connections) can be changed through settings.